# JS Regex Help Domain Catcher

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm currently creating a JavaScript Regex and I can't seem to figure out how to match a specific domain. Here is an example.

I need to create a regex that matches any domain that strictly contains (text.com) but not two domain levels deep. For example:

- text.com --> match
- test.text.com --> match

foo.test.text.com will not match as it contains two domain levels past text.com (foo and test) if that makes sense.

So far, I have been able to create a regex that can find any match for one domain level past text.com but it still matches domains it should not. I'm thinking it needs a negative lookahead assertion which I tried but maybe configured incorrectly?

I am using

```
(?<!\w)(\w+.{1}text\.com)
```

Here is a link to my current regex editor, any help would be greatly appreciated!
https://regex101.com/r/P053fv/1

Example of how many current regex fails: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtD9R.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex will match domains ending with text.com and not having more than 1 subdomain:

```
^([^.]+?\.)?text\.com$
```

- `^` from the start of the string
- `([^.]+?\.)?` an optional string group ending with one dot
- `text\.com` following text.com
- `$` end of string

https://regex101.com/r/O7zr4K/1

| Matching | Non matching |
| --- | --- |
| text.com | foo.test.text.com |
| test.text.com | foo2.no.match.here.text.com |